# vim internal terminal run multiple commands at a time

Tags: vim

I create some useful vim command aliases like:

```
command GccAndRun !gcc main.c && ./a.out
```

However, it's better to run `a.out` and check source code in same window.

I here about vim internel terminal, so I write the follwing sentence:

```
command GccAndRun terminal gcc main.c && ./a.out
```

But given error message: `gcc: error: &&: No such file or directory` in opened terminal.

I don't know how to fix it. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by fixing your initial command, which can't work as-is:

```
command GccAndRun !gcc main.c && ./a.out
```

Now, `:terminal` unfortunately doesn't accept constructs like `cmd1 && cmd2` or `cmd1 | cmd2`, so you will need a workaround:

- create a shell script, say `run.sh`, that does `gcc main.c && ./a.out` for you and do:

  ```
  command GccAndRun terminal run.sh
  ```

  Pros:

  - you can put whatever you want in that script

  Cons:

  - may need non-trivial scripting if you want to pass filenames, etc.
  - pollutes the project
  - is project-dependent
  - doesn't leave you in terminal mode
- use the `++shell` option, which tells Vim to run the given command in a non-interactive shell:

  ```
  command GccAndRun terminal ++shell gcc main.c && ./a.out
  ```

  Pros:

  - you can input whatever command you want
  - doesn't pollute the project
  - is project-agnostic

  Cons:

  - doesn't leave you in terminal mode

See `:help :terminal`.

Comment: Thanks, typo fixed.  `++shell` meets my need, and what's the meaning of **doesn't leave you in terminal mode**?  I run in this way, and everything is similar to without `++shell`. I can't find a clear explanation in vim help doc.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put that in both workarounds.